# How to build an osx universal binary with different code for intel and arm architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

My goal is to create a universal/fat binary of my app, my understanding is that means xcode will create an intel/x86_64 build and an M1/arm build and package them together.
My code uses intel intrinsics which I can replace with NEON in the arm build but to do so I need a way to create a conditional block at compile time for the target architecture.
Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

What I've tried so far:

```
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
#if defined TARGET_CPU_ARM64
    #include <sse2neon.h> //NEON intristics
#endif
#if defined TARGET_CPU_X86_64
    #include <emmintrin.h> //Intel intristics
#endif
```

When this was used Xcode tried to compile the arm code into the x86_64 build which failed. I suppose both targets are defined at compile time but Xcode builds intel then arm objects separately so there must be a way for it to define which is which that I can use.

Comment: All the TARGET_CPU_XXX are defined.  Some are defined to be `1`, others to be `0`.

Comment: Ooooh right, I've changed it to '#if (TARGET_CPU_ARM64 == 1)' and it's working perfectly now. Thank you @Eljay !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, with help from the comments (thank you!)

I was misusing the definitions, all these are defined in the header but only the relevant ones are set to 1, changing my "#ifdef x" to "#if x == 1" was the solution.

```
#if (TARGET_CPU_ARM64 == 1)
    #include <sse2neon.h>
#elif (TARGET_CPU_X86_64 == 1)
    #include <emmintrin.h>
#endif
```